# How to modify a gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, mongomapper

I have a gem to which I'd like to do few changes.

I have it defined in my Gemfile as follows:

```
gem 'mongo_mapper", :git => "git://github.com/jnunemaker/mongomapper", :branch => "rails3"
```

I was not able to find it in `/usr/local/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
bundle show mongo_mapper
```