# Rails - Mailboxer gem : adding relationships to Conversation

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, relationship, mailboxer

We are currently using [Mailboxer](https://github.com/ging/mailboxer) in our project and it's doing fine.

Now we want to add `Requests` to `Conversations`. Basically, the idea would be to add a

```
has_one :request, :foreign_key => 'request_id'
```

but we cannot access `conversation.rb` since it belongs to the gem.

We've read about customizing gem ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8689306/can-i-edit-the-gem-installed-using-gem-install-or-from-my-gemfile) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4037398/how-to-modify-a-gem)) but the offered solutions don't seem fine.

What would be the best way to achieve what we want?

Can we:

- extend a gem model to a custom one that we can edit?
- have a 'clean' way to edit conversation.rb ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

This question is over a year old, but I thought I'd share my solution to a similar problem I had on a Rails 4 environment.

Essentially:

1. Create a new child model that inherits from `Mailboxer::Conversation` model
2. Add the associations to the new child model.
3. Use the [`becomes`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence.html#method-i-becomes) method when creating associations

To illustrate, here's my new model file, called `AppConversation` inheriting from the `Mailboxer::Conversation` class:

```
class AppConversation < Mailboxer::Conversation
  has_one :request, inverse_of: :app_conversation
end
```

The corresponding association in the `Request` model class:

```
class Request < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :app_conversation, inverse_of: :request
end
```

Then, wherever in the code I need to access the association, I first obtain the mailboxer's conversation object via the APIs provided from the mailboxer gem, and then use the ActiveRecord `becomes` method to create/modify/read the association. For example:

```
def some_controller_action
  # get a mailboxer conversation
  @conversation = current_user.mailbox.conversations.find(params[:id])

  # get the request object associated to the conversation
  @request = @conversation.becomes(AppConversation).request

  # create a new request association
  new_request = Request.new
  @conversation.becomes(AppConversation).request = new_request
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I really like @richsinn approach (very clean, but you have to remember calling `becomes`). Another solution would be to use some meta programming to add some methods directly to the `Mailboxer::Conversation`class. E.g. the following code could be added to config/initializers/mailboxer.rb:

```
Mailboxer.setup do |config|
  [...]
end

Mailboxer::Conversation.class_eval do
  belongs_to :request
end
```

Ideally, we could put this code in something like app/models/conversation.rb, but Rails won't load this file automatically when we call `Mailboxer::Conversation`.